# Trouble binding events in TKinter

Tags: python, user-interface, event-handling, tkinter

For background: most of my experience is ruby/rails. I'm trying to help a friend by building a simple GUI app that updates an Excel file and don't have much experience w/ Python or TKinter. The goal is to have a simple form, the user enters a number, and another form is shown with a drop down menu. I decided to store the given number in a global variable as I have had trouble trying to pass a variable between the two frames. I cannot manage to both set the global variable and switch to the second frame. Other questions/issues I've had are in ## marked comments.

Alternatively, if anyone has any ideas on the best way to make a cross platform app that can access an MDB or excel file, I'm all ears. It kind of blows me away how difficult this has been. Thanks for any help.

```
import Tkinter as tk

TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")
ID_NUMBER = None

class StatusApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (EntryPage, StatusPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(EntryPage)

    def show_frame(self, c):
        '''Show a frame for the given class'''
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()

class EntryPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter ID:", font=TITLE_FONT)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        ## Using the lambda works to switch frames, but I need to be able to execute 
        ## multiple statements.
        # entry.bind('<Return>', lambda event: controller.show_frame(StatusPage))

        ## In examples I've seen, callback has been used without the empty parens, not sure
        ## why they're needed?
        self.entry.bind('<Return>', self.callback())
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry.focus_set()

    def callback(self):
        ## I noticed the following gets fired once the program starts
        print 'hello'

        ## For some reason it says that entry doesn't have the attribute 'set'. I don't
        ## understand this as I'm calling it like a method.
        self.entry.set('hello')

        ## Ultimately setting the global ID_NUMBER variable is one of the main goals of this
        ## function
        ID_NUMBER = self.entry.get()

        ## I haven't been able to switch frames from within this function, only w/ a lambda as
        ## seen on line 34.
        # show_frame(StatusPage())

class StatusPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
        label = tk.Label(self, text="ID: ", font=TITLE_FONT)
        optionList = ('train', 'plane', 'boat')
        selected_opt = tk.StringVar()
        selected_opt.set(ID_NUMBER)
        menu = tk.OptionMenu(self, selected_opt, *optionList)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Save", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(EntryPage))
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        menu.pack()
        button.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = StatusApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The object of a binding must be a reference to a callable function. Lambda is often used in this context because it creates an anonymous function and returns a reference).

When you do `...bind(..., self.callback())`, you are calling that function at the time the bind statement executes. In the code you make the comment `## I noticed the following gets fired once the program starts`; this is why.  The result of this function call is what is associated with the binding. Quite often, and in your specific case, this is the value `None`. You must omit the `()`

In the code comments you wrote

```
## For some reason it says that entry doesn't have the attribute 'set'. I don't
## understand this as I'm calling it like a method.
self.entry.set('hello')
```

What makes you believe an entry widget has a `set` method? No documentation that I know of makes that claim. The error message is correct, the entry widget has no attribute named "set" (functions are considered attributes in this context).